# Call android native gallery and fill it with my DB photos

Tags: android, database, gallery

It is possible to call android native gallery and fill the gallery with images that is in my database?
Example:
my app take a photo and store the photo in a Database. I want to make a button to call android native gallery and fill the gallery with my photos that are in my database.
It is possible or I need to make a whole gallery just for it?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can modify what the native gallery displays, but you can save photos there and just store the paths in your database. I'd prefer to create a new gallery specifically for them.

Comment: Because I want to hide my photos from native gallery. I think I will need to create a whole gallery for it. Thank you very much

Comment: I think that would be the best way since the content is app-specific.